# Is it appropriate to ask why my promotion was not announced?

Tags: management, communication, promotion

In my workplace, all promotions are announced to our department via email. I was promoted recently. Although there was an email announcing everyone else who got promoted, no email was sent announcing my promotion.

I understand that my boss is busy and this may have slipped his mind, but such recognition is important to me. Is it inappropriate to address this with my boss? Should I just swallow my pride and need for recognition and just move on?

Comment: Is the promotion just a change in pay? or dose it also come with a visible change in scope or visible change in responsibility?

Answer (score 18):

If it's important enough that you are bothered you should ask your boss if this was an oversight.  If they say the policy has changed or it doesn't apply in this situation then consider swallowing your pride and moving on but the best way to get what you want is often to ask for it.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your confirmation. Sometimes, office politics and quirks of people around make me lose sight of what should be simple and addressed like responsible adults who can discuss concerns as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's appropriate, and more than that, you *should* do it. It's the right way to be assertive; you have a *right* to this announcement. Otherwise, just letting it go sends a message to your boss and others about your lack of self-respect.

Unfortunately, plenty of managers make exaggerated promises or illusory decisions. A public announcement isn't just a nicety. It's the company and your manager putting a stake in the ground and publicly proclaiming their decision and their confidence in you. It sets the tone and expectations of everyone else.

Comment: I don't know if they have a "right" to this announcement. Maybe if it's in the contract.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should request your manager to issue the announcement as it will surely be essential for you to deliver on your job. Even more so if the promotion changes the roles you were previously playing and if you are supposed to have any direct reports working under you.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this opinion presents an alternative perspective and might get some pushback. But I will offer it, as I believe it could help balance the discussion and be useful as a way to consider a different stance on the issue.

We have all-hands-on-deck staff meetings where new employees are introduced. But such meetings are infrequent, and can happen 2 or 3 months after the individual has been with the organization. It is also possible that if a few people joined in the same period, someone could be omitted by accident. Did the individual lose out in some way from not being announced in such a meeting? Not at all. The people who need to work with them already know about them, no problem. It is not a big deal if the announcement is made in a future meeting, or even not at all. They are not less a member of their team for it, nor are they paid less, nor recognized and acknowledged by their colleagues, immediate supervisor and leadership (at least no less than other new hires).

I wonder why is such recognition important to you. Promotion is what counts, not emailing everyone about it. Think about what's worse: a lot of rhetoric about professional growth but few actual opportunities for advancement, or promotion with some cracks in the dissemination process.

In sum, I view this situation as an opportunity to practice humility.

People like to think of themselves (or to have others consider them) as humble and not vain, only to agonize over missed opportunities to have their name proclaimed to the world. You might check what caused omission, but I wouldn't insist on this being 'corrected.'

To the point that 'official' recognition will somehow make a difference professionally, in terms of being able to justify taking on new responsibilities or supervisory duties.

My perspective is that those who need to know about your promotion for work reasons, will become aware of it one way or another. People also recognize and respect humility, and lose respect when they notice hints at the opposite. I would consider this, and err on the side of caution in this case.

Who knows, perhaps there is a good reason for this announcement not being made about you. Perhaps you will be better off from it in the long run, even though it may be less apparent at the moment.

For these reasons, I suggest to take a little more time, use patience, and see how things go. If there is clear evidence that lack of announcement of the promotion results in some disadvantage, then you can always follow up on it. It's never too late for that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially a few separate questions:

- Is it inherent to you doing your job that everybody knows that your role has changed. e.g. a Developer to Project Manager transition is just not successful if the colleagues don't know about the role change.
- Is there a reason not to communicate it right now (Department politics, difficult colleagues)
- Do you have the promotion in written and confirmed form (if yes, relax, then this is not a case of somebody back-pedaling)

The last question you can answer yourself, the first questions you can address informally with your boss. E.g. Hello, "i was wondering if and how we should communicate the role change in the team."